# Referring to the type being defined in type parameters

Tags: scala, generics, types

I'm trying to come up with a type safe messaging system. Right now the best I've come up with is this:

```
trait Component
trait Message[From <: Component, -To <: Handler[From]]

trait Handler[From <: Component]{
  type MessageType <: Message[From, this.type]

  def handle(message: MessageType): Unit;
}
```

What I'd like is something more like this:

```
trait Component
trait Message[From <: Component, -To <: Handler[From]]

trait Handler[From <: Component, MessageType <: Message[From, this.type]]{

  def handle(message: MessageType): Unit;
}
```

but the compiler complains about using `this.type` in the type parameters. Is there some way for me to refer to the type I'm defining in the type parameters so I can use the syntax I'd like?

It's clearly possible for the type system to do what I want I'd just like it to use the syntax I like.

--EDIT--

I think I've found a solution.

```
trait Component
trait Message[From <: Component, 
              To <: Handler[From, To, MessageType], 
              MessageType <: Message[From, To, MessageType]]

trait Handler[From <: Component, 
              To <: Handler[From, To, MessageType], 
              MessageType <: Message[From, To, MessageType]]{

  def handle(message: MessageType ): Unit;
}
```

A bit more verbose in the type parameters but it works well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need `MessageType` in the type parameters to accomplish what you want. Instead make `MessageType` equal to `Message[From, this.type]`.

```
trait Handler[From <: Component] {
  type MessageType = Message[From, this.type]

  def handle(message: MessageType): Unit;
}
```

Consider making message covariant in its first parameter.

Note that `this.type` does *not* refer to the type that you are defining. `this.type` is a type that has only a single value: `this`. `this` doesn't exist outside the trait body, and therefore cannot be used in the type parameters. If you really need to refer to the type the trait will be mixed into, you need [F-bounded polymorphism](http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html#fbounded).

Comment: So the problem with this solution is that you can't use a subtype of Message[From, this.type] as the parameter to handle making it much less usefull for pattern matching.

Comment: @Meshelton I don't understand what you mean. You can definitely pass a subtype to `handle`, methods are always contravariant in their parameters.

Comment: you can pass a subtype but you couldn't declare the method like this `def handle(message: SubtypeOfMessageType): Unit` you get a compiler error which makes sense.